# Parsing parentheses: smie vs syntax table

Tags: smie, syntax-table

I am maintaining a mode for a programming language with... let's say
"annoying" syntax constructs.

For example, the angle brackets (no idea if it is the correct word)
`<` and `>` are parentheses. However, the word `->` is also a valid
token, does not count as a closing parenthesis, and to top it all,
should only occur *inside* a pair of `<` and `>`.

If I understand correctly, there is no way to get emacs to recognise
this using only syntax tables, is that correct?

Hence the question: the mode is using `smie` for what cannot be done
with syntax tables, and [smie is also the
canonical answer to define multi-character parens](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10633301/1083706). So I guess that I will have to get smie to replace the syntax table for this pair of parentheses.

The question is: *what does need to be set up in smie, in order to
replace syntax table features for a particular paren pair?*

The question is motivated by [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/SMIE-Lexer.html#SMIE-Lexer): it is advised to let syntax tables do their job whenever
possible. Hence, I'm afraid that with a naive set-up, I will run into
problems later, or worse, that it will cause problems behind the
scenes.

What I can think of (aka the "naive set-up" mentioned above):

- removing the paren category for characters `<` and `>` in the
  syntax table;
- adding `("<" whatever ">")` in the BNF grammar;
- making the lexer recognize the token `<` (resp `>`) as `"<"`
  (resp. `">"`) instead of `""`.

*Is it enough?*

And, in case it would actually be, bonus question: *is there any good reason to leave the handling
of sexps to the syntax table instead of smie?*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Speed is a good reason to let the paren-matching be performed by syntax-tables where possible.  In your case, the "parens" are not multi-char, so you can definitely use syntax-tables for them.  In order to avoid treating `->` as a paren closer, you can setup a `syntax-propertize-function` which modifies the syntax of those `>` which appear in `->`.  Something like

```
(setq-local syntax-propertize-function
            (syntax-propertize-rules
             ("-\\(>\\)"
              (1 (let ((ppss (save-excursion (syntax-ppss (match-beginning 0)))))
                   (and (nth 1 ppss) ;; Inside at least one level of parens.
                        (eq ?< (char-after (nth 1 ppss))) ;; Last level is <...>
                        (string-to-syntax ".")))))))
```

Comment: Aah, good ol' XY problem, good that I added the background before the question, then. Thanks! I'm not sure to completely understand your code, though: is it absolutely needed to check that we are inside a pair of `<` and `>`? I mentioned it in the question because it causes this token to *always* confuse the parser, but where would be the harm in "defusing" all `>` following a `-`?

Comment: There'd be no harm to Emacs.  I just wrote the code this way to show how to do it, if you need it.  But if `->` won't appear inside `(...)`, or if when it does you don't want it to close the `(`, then you don't need to be so picky.  Then you can just use `(syntax-propertize-rules ("-\\(>\\)" (1 ".")))`.

Comment: It shouldn't appear out of `<...>` (not in syntactically correct code), and if it did I wouldn't want it to close anything (it is an operator which sadly happens to contain a parenthesis). Actually, now that you mention it, I guess that with your code, if `->` appears out of a `<` construct, instead of closing the `)`, the parser will complain about a mismatched parenthesis, won't it?

Comment: Yes and no: the paren-mismatch is only checked in some rare circumstances (e.g. when you type it), but not when you do `C-M-f`.